# Bash Filling Array in Parallel

Tags: arrays, bash

Trying to stop using files output to store data from a parallel for loop. I want to run the output of array through paralleled commands using input from the array and store the results when its completed in the array in the correct order.

Logic-ish code:

```
    for i in `do some stuff`
    do

    bunch of stuff based on variables in the loop run in parallel but output saved in the right order

    done
```

Broken Code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    IFS=$'\n'
    for i in $(seq 1 1 10)
    do

    export MYBROKENARRAY+=(`echo POTATO;wait`) &  

    done

    sleep 1
    echo MYBROKENARRAY IS "${MYBROKENARRAY[@]}"
```

if I keep the & I get my parallel but the output is not stored in the array as expected

expedited output is:

MYBROKENARRAY IS POTATO POTATO POTATO POTATO POTATO POTATO POTATO POTATO POTATO POTATO

This is how I to it today with ugly file output ... :(

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    IFS=$'\n'
    for i in $(seq 1 1 10)
    do

    echo POTATO > out_${i}.txt &

    done
    cat out_*.txt
```

Comment: Create an array of N elements and give each child process a number X between 0 and N-1. Each process will fill the array on entry X.

Comment: You have a concurrency problem that is dealt with by database engines, using transactions and atomic operations. It is possible to emulate this by having a separate process that receive entries and is in charge of adding them to the array. It will prevent concurrent destructive accesses to the array by two different processes.

Comment: ``for i in `do some stuff` `` is almost certainly wrong; see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
MY_SHOUTY_WORKING_ARRAY=( $(parallel -k echo POTATO ::: {1..10} ))
```

**Output**

```
echo "${MY_SHOUTY_WORKING_ARRAY[*]}"
POTATO 1
POTATO 2
POTATO 3
POTATO 4
POTATO 5
POTATO 6
POTATO 7
POTATO 8
POTATO 9
POTATO 10
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel has `parset` which is made for this:

```
parset my_array -j10 'sleep 10; seq {}' ::: {1..10}
echo "${my_array[3]}"
```

This also deals nicely with output containing special characters such as newlines.

You activate `parset` with:

```
env_parallel --install
<<start a new shell>>
```